# How can I remove LeaseRenewer error in spark unit testing?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, sbt

I'm running spark unit tests with a shared instance of local spark from sbt console.

Scala version: 2.11.11
Spark version: 2.0.2_cdh5.8.0_1
Sbt version:  0.13.16

I have multiple modules. The tests are not failing but it retries until it fails with OutOfMemory exception.
When I ran sbt test for a single module everything works fine. But when I'm running sbt test for all then I get the fallowing exception:

```
LeaseRenewer: Failed to renew lease for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-465806268_61] for 76 seconds.  Will retry shortly ...
java.net.ConnectException: Call From C02TM0QGG8WL/10.120.214.244 to localhost:52634 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor197.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.renewLease(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.renewLease(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:590)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor124.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.renewLease(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.renewLease(DFSClient.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.renew(LeaseRenewer.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.run(LeaseRenewer.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer.access$700(LeaseRenewer.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.LeaseRenewer$1.run(LeaseRenewer.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 16 more
```

How can I resolve this issue? I tried to increase memory in tests also but with no luck.
Thanks.